# jQuery append issue without removing original elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wrote some code for practicing my jQuery. When I wrote this code, I found out it works fine with only using append() and without removing any original `tr` elements in the `table`. How does it work — could someone explain it to me? [here is the complete code](http://jsfiddle.net/player889/84vE9/2/). Thanks!

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
     var list = a();
     var last = $('#table').find("tr").length;     
    $('#table').find("tr").each(function (index, element) {
            $(this).prepend($("<button/>").text("↑").bind('click', function () {
                up($(this).parent(), last);
            }));
            $(this).prepend($("<button/>").text("↓").bind('click', function () {
                down($(this).parent(), last);
            }));
        });
        $('#table').before($('<button />').text("reset").on('click', function () {
            reset(list);
        }));
      });
function up(tr, last) {
    if (0 != tr.index()) {
        var prevTr = tr.prev();
        tr.after(prevTr);
    }
}
function down(tr, last) {
    if (last - 1 != tr.index()) {
        var nextTr = tr.next();
        tr.before(nextTr);
    }
}
var reset = function (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $("#table").append(list[i]);
    }
};
var a = function () {
    var list = [];
    $('#table tr').each(function () {
        list.push($(this));
    });
    return list;
};
```

Comment: it works fine with only using append() and without removing any original tr elements in the table -- What works fine ?

Comment: Ya, what is your issue? What is your question???

Comment: @A.Wolff my question is : using " append() " in my reset function, it suppose adding the contents to the selector, but in my case, it does not add any elements. "it replace the elements", i do not know what happen

Comment: @player889 but 'reset' suggest that you want to reset the list or function is misnamed, isn't it? Do you want instead to add new elements or what?

Comment: @A.Wolff reset function is set tr elements to the original order. when i first wrote the reset function, it should be doing " remove all tr elements which has switch by up and down button (demo) and then using append() to set the original tr elements back up". the problem is : it does not need to remove the tr elements, just use append() will achieve what i want to do in my case. How it is replaced by using append().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Be aware, appending already existing element just move it. I guess maybe you want to clone it:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/84vE9/3/)

```
var reset = function (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $("#table").append(list[i].clone(true));
    }
};
```

But then, reset function is misnamed...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

waits for the page and all elements to be loaded

```
     var list = a();
     var last = $('#table').find("tr").length;
```

sets up specific variables, in this case list is the function `a()` defined later in the page and last gets the length of the last tr in the table.

```
    $('#table').find("tr").each(function (index, element) {
```

sets up a loop through each tr element on in the table with id #table

```
            $(this).prepend($("<button/>").text("↑").bind('click', function () {
                up($(this).parent(), last);
            }));
```

Because you are inside the loop, `$(this)` represents the tr that the loop is currently on. It then prepends a button and adds a click listener on this button. When the button is pressed, it will call the function up, which is defined later on, with the buttons parent as the first parameter and last (defined earlier) as the second

```
            $(this).prepend($("<button/>").text("↓").bind('click', function () {
                down($(this).parent(), last);
            }));
```

This adds another button, but calls down() instead of up()

```
        });
```

End of the loop.

```
        $('#table').before($('<button />').text("reset").on('click', function () {
            reset(list);
        }));
```

This adds a button before the table that when clicked calls the reset function with list as the only parameter, list is set to a().

```
      });
function up(tr, last) {
    if (0 != tr.index()) {
        var prevTr = tr.prev();
        tr.after(prevTr);
    }
}
```

This function is called when moving an item up, it first checks to see if the index is not 0 (so not the first element as this couldn't be moved up) if it is not then  it puts the previous tr after the variable tr. Which in this case is the parent to the button (or the current tr)

```
function down(tr, last) {
    if (last - 1 != tr.index()) {
        var nextTr = tr.next();
        tr.before(nextTr);
    }
}
```

Works exactly the same as the function above, but in the opposite direction.

```
var reset = function (list) {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        $("#table").append(list[i]);
    }
};
```

This function is saved in the variable reset, it loops through each tr (defined in a()) and appends it to the table,

```
var a = function () {
    var list = [];
    $('#table tr').each(function () {
        list.push($(this));
    });
    return list;
};
```

This function creates and returns an array which loops through each tr and adds to that array. So we know the original state and can return to it.

Comment: thanks your post. but could you describe more clear about the reset function i have, this is confuse me. Using append() does not add any content to the selector in my case, it replace the contents i have wrote with append() command. Why it is replaced the tr elements which i use append() on my reset function.

Comment: See @A. Wolff's answer